# Add new column at specified position programmatically in C# Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview with 5(0-5) columns. All the rows value I retrieve from the hashtable created. 
Now I've set a condition that state if column 4 contain empty value from hashtable then add new column next to column 4 which makes the new added column index at position 5 and the value of hashtable previously for column 5 change to column 7.

I do the code like this:

```
    int number = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[0].Value = result;                                 //id       
    dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[1].Value = newAddress;                             //ip    
    dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[2].Value = (string)((Hashtable)ht[1])["value"];    //name
    dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[3].Value = (string)((Hashtable)ht[2])["value"];    //description
    if (!ht.ContainsValue(3))
        {
          // Create a Save button column
          DataGridViewImageButtonSaveColumn columnSave = new DataGridViewImageButtonSaveColumn();

          // Set column values
          columnSave.Name = "SaveButton";
          columnSave.HeaderText = "";

          //Add the columns to the grid
          dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[4].ReadOnly = false;
          dataGridView1.Columns[5].Add(columnSave);    //im not sure about this codes
          dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[6].Value = (string)((Hashtable)ht[4])["value"];    //count

        } 
        else
        {
          dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[4].Value = (string)((Hashtable)ht[3])["value"];    //location
          dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[5].Value = (string)((Hashtable)ht[4])["value"];    //count
        }
```

However, i'm not sure if I do this right because I receive error at the line commented

```
        dataGridView1.Columns[5].Add(columnSave);    //im not sure about this codes
```

Seems like this code is wrong. Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try `dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(5, columnSave);` instead.

MSDN reference: [DataGridViewColumnCollection.Insert Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumncollection.insert.aspx)

Comment: you mean dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(5, columnSave); ? Thanks mate,its working now.

Comment: Sorry, lil bit more help. If I want this column header to be hidden, just the column header, not the rows value. Is that possible?

Comment: Not too sure, that's a bit unusual. Maybe a property of `columnSave.HeaderCell`. Or add a handler for `columnSave.HeaderCell.Paint`, and do nothing in it. Or you could just set `columnSave.HeaderText = "";` ?

Comment: Those are just ideas though, you should do a bit of investigation and ask a new question if you can't get it working.

Comment: Okay, but now I got new problem, the codes works well. But whenever it loops the condition, it will keep inserting new column, and if the loops like 100,then it insert 100 new columns. Do you have any Idea how to solve this?

Comment: I guess don't add the column inside the loop? Or use a bool to remember whether you added one, and don't do it twice.

Comment: This didn't work. VS does what it wishes. I had to run Columns.Clear() every time to enforce my ordering.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to insert a checkbox to certain column of Data grid:

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chk = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();

dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(**certain column number**, chk);
```

for example if you want to add checkbox to column 1 you mus type

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, chk);
```